# How to interpret glm() result that include factor type in R

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model

I'm using glm() function to get result of logistic regression. 
But i can't interpret the result.
In my data, there are nominal variables and target variable is categorical variable.

I know that I can use independent variable that is factor type.

I implemented and this is my result.

```
> glmresult <- glm(Creditability~., data=ccc, family="binomial")
> glmresult

Call:  glm(formula = Creditability ~ ., family = "binomial", data = ccc)

Coefficients:
                       (Intercept)                    Account.Balance2                    Account.Balance3  
                          -0.64926                             0.37831                             0.96295  
                  Account.Balance4          Duration.of.Credit..month.  Payment.Status.of.Previous.Credit1  
                           1.75194                            -0.02833                            -0.18516  
Payment.Status.of.Previous.Credit2  Payment.Status.of.Previous.Credit3  Payment.Status.of.Previous.Credit4  
                           0.60384                             0.97353                             1.51219
```

As you can see, there are same variables like Account.Balance1,2,3~~. It is a factor type data set. I realized that if i use factor type, the result is posted like above table.

How can I interpret the result?

Comment: Levels are coded as dummy variables. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Tim I know that levels are coded as dummy variables. But i want to know what variables are effectively affect to target variable. I mean that I want to know relation between dependent variable and independent variable. But factor data type is splited..... Then I can't know relation between them.. Just I can know relation between dependent variable and   factor data's levels...

Comment: Well, yes, this is what regression is about... What do you mean by relation between levels of the factor..? They are exclusive, so the relation is that each of them is perfectly negatively correlated with each other one. I don't understand what do you mean...